# How do I import packages from a jar-file, into a servlet, which is running on tomcat 8?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, apache-kafka

I'm currently working on setting up an tomcat8-server and want to write an servlet on it, which handles POST-requests with sensorvalues attached to it.

I want this sensordata to be emitted to Apache Kafka through a producer, setted up in the servlet. I wanted to set up a test-http-servlet with the code from "[How to send a message via Kafka.Producer from a java servlet to Kafka](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17874793/how-to-send-a-message-via-kafka-producer-from-a-java-servlet-to-kafka)" to learn writing my own.

But on compiling with:`javac -cp /home/tobias/apache-tomcat-8.5.8/lib/servlet-api.jar HTTPServlet.java`

, I get the following message:

`HTTPServlet.java:19: error: package kafka.producer does not exist
import kafka.producer.ProducerConfig;
                     ^
HTTPServlet.java:20: error: package kafka.javaapi.producer does not exist
import kafka.javaapi.producer.ProducerData;
                             ^`

I did already put the "kafka_2.11-0.10.1.0.jar", which contains the "kafka.producer.ProducerConfig"-class into the "WEB-INF/lib" folder, but It does not seem to work.

This "kafka_2.11-0.10.1.0.jar" was located in the "libs" folder of "kafka_2.11-0.10.1.0", which can be downloaded from the kafka-website.

So I wanted to ask, how I would get this working and If anyone knows, where the 2. missing file is located in the latest release of kafka.

Comment: You need to put all those jars in the command line -cp option just like you did with servlet-api.jar

Comment: You should start using an IDE rather than attempting to compile something less trivial than a "hello, world" app on the command line.

Comment: Thank you very much!! Do you also know where the "ProducerData"-class went in the new release of kafka?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem (**thanks to Strelok**) by adding the additional api.jar-files to my compile-command:`javac -cp /home/tobias/apache-tomcat-8.5.8/lib/servlet-api.jar:/home/tobias
/apache-tomcat-8.5.8/webapps/HTTPServlet/WEB-INF/lib/kafka_2.11-0.10.1.0.jar HTTPServlet.java`

The import for the ProducerData: `import kafka.javaapi.producer.ProducerData;` is not possible anymore, because the ProducerData.class was removed from the 0.6 to 0.7 release of kafka. I recommend using the ProducerRecord.class (worked for my test-example).